# How to create .Net library that reference NuGet package without exposing the package public methods and classes

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, .net-standard

**Main Goal:** I want to create a library with fewer dependencies as possible.

**The Problem:**

I have a `.Net Standard` library (`a.dll`) that references a NuGet package (`package`) for internal usages.
I tried to achieve the following behavior when a user referencing `a.dll`:

1. The user will not have any access to the `package` classes and methods.
2. The user will be able to reference a different version of the `package` and both versions will be loaded to the process.

How can I achieve this behavior?

**Possible Solution:** Copy the package code and change the assembly name and all the modifier access to internal. Big disadvantage: very difficult to maintain.

Comment: You can't do that. You aren't removing the dependency in any way. Any packages that use *your* NuGet package won't have to reference the third-party directly anyway

Comment: Especially for #2, that's simply not possible in .NET whether Old or Core. An application (more specifically, an Application Domain) can only load a single assembly version.

Comment: Your possible solution is your only solution, you will need to keep in sync and maintain your copy.

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev that's not a solution at all. In fact, I don't see what the actual problem is. Reducing dependencies means using fewer dependencies, not trying to hide them. The dependency is still there, just harder to access. And by definition, maintain

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no it is not true, in .Net Framework different versions of same library can be loaded side by side via binding redirects and `codeBase` attribute.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will give an example. Let say my library reference `Newtonsoft.Json` version `11` and the user want to reference `Newtonsoft.Json` version `12` that have breaking changes. I don't want that my library will break his logic. If I will copy all the code of `Newtonsoft.Json` and I will change the assembly name and the access modifiers. Both of the version can load together under the same process.

Comment: The answer to this is to release a new version of your NuGet package that works with the latest JSON.NET version. And use appropriate version constraints so that each version specifies the JSON.NET version it works with. Otherwise you'll have to not just clone the entire JSON.NET repo (which isn't trivial), you'll also be responsible for patching and any security issues. Never mind the configuration issues and namespace hell cloning would cause.

Comment: It can make any sense only if you are trying to hide some private library from your internal nuget source, but it is not your case as I see.

Comment: For the last 15 years developers in all languages are comfortable with packages and transient dependencies and don't want to have *anything* to do with the big fat DLLs used in the 1990s and 2000s. Nobody is going to trust a third party library author to provide support and security patching *other* libraries. Especially popular and well maintained libraries like JSON.NET

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos and @AlexeyRumyantsev, First thank you for the comments. Update to the latest version will not always work. In my case, I use `Unity` container and my library is used by visual studio extensions which loaded to visual studio process with other extensions (That may use other versions of `Unity`).